# count odd numbers of an N-ary tree

Tags: python

I am struggling with this exercise. It tells me to count all odd numbers present in an N-Ary. The exercise demands me to use recursion

Take a look at the following tree

```
              5                                           
      ________|_____________                        
     |          |           |                     
     20         4           6                     
     |     _____|______                      
     11   |   |  |  |  |                    
          10  2  9  8  7                  
            __|__                        
           |     |                    
           3     1
```

There are 12 numbers in it. Among these numers, 6 of them are odd which is the output i am looking for. However, the code i have written doesn't solve the issue and i don't understand why.

The function i have implemented returns 0 which is incorrect.

```
def es7(tree):
    n = 0
    for element in tree.f: 
        n = es7(element)
        if element.id % 2 == 1: 
            n += 1 
    return n  
 

class Nodo:
    def __init__(self,V):
        self.id=V
        self.f=[]


################### DA QUI IN GIÙ SONO SOLO FUNZIONI NECESSARIE PER I TEST #####################

def fromLista(lista):
    '''Crea l'albero da una lista [valore, listafigli]
           In cui lista figli contiene alberi o e' la lista vuota. '''
    r=Nodo(lista[0])
    r.f=[fromLista(x) for x in lista[1]]
    return r

def toLista(nodo):
    ''' Converte l'albero in una lista di liste [valore, listafigli]'''
    return [nodo.id, [toLista(x) for x in nodo.f]]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach to this problem; is to simply to do a level order traversal of the N-ary tree.

Consider the following iterative solutions, which can give some insights into writing your recursive solution.

To re-write your code, I would do something on these lines.
Consider this snippet below:

```
def es7(tree):
    q, level = [tree], []
    while any(q):
        level.append([node.id for node in q])
        q = [child for node in q for child in node.f if child]

    ans = 0
    for l in level:
        for num in l:
            if num & 1:
                ans += num
    return ans
```

Consider the snippet of code below:  (Non-recursive Solution)

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val=None, children=None):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children

class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: 'Node') -> List[List[int]]:
        if not root:
            return 
        
        q = deque([root])
        level = 0
        result = []
        
        while q:
            result.append([])
            for i in range(len(q)):
                node = q.popleft()
                result[level].append(node.val)
                
                for c in node.children:
                    q.append(c)
            
            level += 1
        
        return result
```

In the above code, `result` will have all the elements of the `n-ary` tree according to levels. Parse through list, and add all the odd numbers.

That would be something along these lines:-

```
for level in result:
    for num in result:
        if num & 1:
           ans += num
```

Alternatively you could also add-up all the `odd-numbers` as you are traversing the tree.

Comment: You realize this approach is both explicitly not what the OP asked for, more complicated, and involving needlessly more advanced Python features, such as type hinting or classes? The OP had an 8 line solution that was almost working... Besides, your current implementation assumes that `bool(tree)` is `true`, and your "recursive" solution is not recursive.

Comment: Removed the "recursive" word from the initial code-snippet. Thanks for catching that. I wanted to add an iterative solution, so that it can help OP to visualize and come-up with recursive solution, and give some insights on alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing `n` at each iteration. What you probably want to do is something like

```py
def es7(tree):
    n = 0
    for element in tree.f: 
        n += es7(element) # <-- note the `+=`
        if element.id % 2 == 1: 
            n += 1 
    return n
```

However, I think this code is still not completely sound (depending on your representation of a tree), which you might realize on a tree with a single, odd number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it outputs 5 probably because it is not counting the first value. How can i solve it?

Comment: I think i solved it, but i had to write another function! Now i am just trying to write less code

Comment: @alex108 it's actually possible to just modify your existing function (without making it longer) to make it work. Just ask yourself exactly what your function should do, and then re-examine your existing code.